# NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/LifecycleListener

Tags: java, class, libgdx

I am trying to use the libgdx controllers extension and i am getting this :

Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/LifecycleListener

When i try to load the Controllers class for the first time, from the desktop project

this is my main projects jars:
[image: who looks at image descriptions? , what's wrong with you]

and this is my desktop's project jars:
[image: who looks at image descriptions? , what's wrong with you]

Comment: `LifecycleListener` is a newer class in Libgdx.  Perhaps you have a version mis-match?  Did you download all the .jars at the same time?  Which version of libgdx are you using?

Comment: Oh , my core libgdx jars were almost 1 year old,i updated them and now everything works fine,  Post your comment as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‛LifecycleListener‛ is a newer class, so likely a version mis-match with an older core Libgdx library.

The Libgdx libraries make no guarantees about compatibility between Libgdx .jars.  All gdx jars your apps use should be from the same build.